# How to get groups of items depending on some condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following task - given a list of objects(time segments).`TimeSegment` is the following type:

```
class TimeSegment
{
       public DateTime Start{get;set;}
       public DateTime End{get;set;}
}
```

This segments are previously grouped by `Start.Date` value. I need to get segments from each group, where `End.TimeOfDay` of one sement is equal to `Start.TimeOfDay` of another element. Is there a way to do such things with LINQ? Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: maybe better you post more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

Create and populate the group:

```
var group = new List<TimeSegment>();

group.Add(new TimeSegment() { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(1), End = DateTime.Today.AddHours(2) });
group.Add(new TimeSegment() { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(3), End = DateTime.Today.AddHours(4) });
group.Add(new TimeSegment() { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(4), End = DateTime.Today.AddHours(5) });
group.Add(new TimeSegment() { Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(6), End = DateTime.Today.AddHours(7) });
```

Get consecutive time segments (ordered by start time):

```
var result = group.Where(t1 => group.Any(t2 => t2.End == t1.Start || t2.Start == t1.End)).OrderBy(t => t.Start).ToList();
```

[See fiddle here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MLk1Y7)

Comment: what if there is more than 2 consecutive time segments?

Comment: It would take them all. I've added a link to fiddle in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
List<TimeSegment> times = db.TimeSegment.Where(t=>t.End.TimeOfDay.Equals(t.Start.Date) ).ToList();
```

Comment: that would compare the start and end of a single timeSegment.